# How to match and replace Email template with dynamic query result in Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, str-replace

We are developing email messaging system where our email html templates are saved in database column

i.e.

> hello user {0}

Another column in the same row has dynamic sql related to this template

i.e.

> Select username as 'To' from userTbl where userid = @userid

I want to write a stored proc which can 
- read the dynamic sql
- execute it and store the result somewhere (may be temp table)
- then get the html template string and match and replace
  result from the sql statment with the html template

The end result should be

> `<html><body>Hello User username</body></html>`

My question is how do I store the dynamic sql value ? Should I not do this in sql and load everything in c# code and perform search and replace via string builder ?

Any idea or suggetion ?

Comment: note: whatever you do, consider the target: search and replace will need html-escaping if the target is html

Comment: Yes target is HTML, its for Email body. Thanks for the info

Comment: For the string search replace (and the HTML-escaping), using the utilities provided in C# will be much easier.  You _can_ do the dynamic SQL in stored procedures...

Comment: Thats why I thought initially but then if some other C# code will call this proc then they will have to implement same logic...if I do it in SQL then It can be called from anywhere.....to do dynamic sql how should I store the sql data...in temp table and then loop through it and perform search replace ?

Comment: That is what a DAL is for - the other code in C# should call your DAL with the Params and template ID, and that one DAL method will handle. If you insist on doing it in SQL, and you're using SQL 2008 or newer, you can create a User Defined Type that contains the token I'd ({0}) and the replacement value, and update your Stored Proc to take a Table Valued Parameter of this new Type, and then run REPLACE statements in your stored procedure from the table input on any tokens within the template. You can also consider CLR stored proc, which can execute a C# method to handle this.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing this in DAL, much better control now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in the database. This is just asking for trouble down the road. Leave the data in the database and do your BL in your application.